# Problem in embed-reaction system. Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So I wrote this code that sends an embed and changes its value/item once the user reacts to certain emoji. It works fine for a single embed but when user asks for same multiple embeds like you see in the image, reaction to a embed changes value of other similar embeds too.

Code part

```py
    @client.command()
    async def embed(ctx):
    current = 1
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f'{current}')
    buttons = [ u"\u25C0", u"\u25FC" , u"\u25B6" ,  u"\U0001F5D1"]
    msg = await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    
    for button in buttons:
        await msg.add_reaction(button)
    while True:
        
        try:
            reaction , user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check = lambda reaction,user: user == ctx.author and reaction.emoji in buttons, timeout = 180.0)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            embed.set_footer(text= "Timeout.")
            await msg.clear_reactions()
        
        else:
            previous_page = current
            if reaction.emoji == u"\u25C0":
                current -= 1
                embed.add_field(name = None, value = f'{current}')
            
            elif reaction.emoji == u"\u25FC":
                if current > 0:
                    current = 0
                    embed.add_field(name = None, value = f'{current}')
                    
            elif reaction.emoji == u"\u25B6":
               
                current += 1
                embed.add_field(name = None, value = f'{current}')
            
            elif reaction.emoji ==  u"\U0001F5D1":
                
                await msg.edit(embed = embed)
                await msg.clear_reactions()

                
            for button in buttons:
                await msg.remove_reaction(button, ctx.author)
            

            if current != previous_page:
                embed.add_field(name = None, value = f'{current}')
                await msg.edit(embed = embed)
```

Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFIyT.jpg

NOTE: The code I've used in my bot is exactly same as this one. I haven't included that and screenshots of those embeds because it is being used for NSFW purposes/images.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe look at your code and ask yourself why this is happening. In your `while True`-loop, you constantly check if the conditions are given. While this is true the bot will always edit the existing embed(s) if possible.

Comment: Can you give me hint of what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because of your check function (line 13)

```py
check = lambda reaction,user: user == ctx.author and reaction.emoji in buttons
```

Here you are checking that the emoji are matching, and the user reacting is the same user that executed the command. But you don't check which message the reaction was added to. To solve this, you could check for the message id, by checking if `reaction.message.id == ctx.message.id` what results in :

```py
check = lambda reaction,user: user == ctx.author and reaction.emoji in buttons and reaction.message.id == msg.id
```

Comment: Now when I click buttons(emoji) nothing happens and I don't get any error message. May be I am doing sth wrong?